# Istanbul how to ignore default value branch for ES6 (babel compiles to ES5)

Tags: ecmascript-6, code-coverage, babeljs, istanbul

In ES5 we can write like this:

```
function(a){
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  a = a || 123;
}
```

how to ignore In ES6?

```
function(a = 123 ){

}
```

I tried this:

```
function(/* istanbul ignore next */a = 123 ){

}
```

but it's not working.

Comment: You can cover the case by writing a test case without passing argument 'a'.

Comment: This is not helpful. In the case when the default opens a socket or writes to a file or mutates a database or performs some other side effect, not passing an argument is not always an option.

Comment: The default probably shouldn't perform those operations because they should be asynchronous. A default initializer cannot be asynchronous.

Comment: Try answering the question instead of debating the merit of the code. You don't know what you don't know.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
function(
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  a = 123
){

}
```

Comment: The inline version works as well. I was just looking for this method while testing. It was driving me crazy that passing nothing/null/undefined didn't satisfy the branching.

const buildConversationSuccess = (/* istanbul ignore next */metadata = {}) => {...........}

Answer (score 1):

When using TypeScript, this was a bit harder to solve since the types must match. I was able to get it to work by passing in `undefined` for each parameter. For example...

```
function testMe(a:SomeType = { foo: 'bar' }, b:AnotherType = { bar: 'baz'}) {
  return a * b;
}
describe('Branch Coverage', () => {
  it('should pass branch coverage', () => {
    expect(testMe(undefined, undefined);
  });
});
```